# Python 3.8.6 (downloading appropriate installer for matplotlib) on laptop with Windows 10

Tags: python

I am doing this on my laptop with Windows 10 OS. Following the instructions on page 323 of the book ("Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes), I am told that I will need an installer for matplotlib and so to go to:   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/  and then to look for a wheel file (a file ending in .whl) that matches my version of python (which is:
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32).
When I go to:   https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files
I see the following 2 files (among many others):

1. matplotlib-3.3.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (8.3 MB)
2. matplotlib-3.3.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (8.5 MB)

From what the author (Eric Matthes) says in the book ("Python Crash Course"), the "cp38" in the above 2 files refers to the version of Python that I presently have (i.e., 3.8.6).  Can someone please tell me which of the above 2 files that I should download and why? I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: the first one is if you have a 32 bit python, and the second one is if you have a 64 bit python

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Python Crash Course. You are working from the first edition of the book, which is growing increasingly out of date. Also, I believe you are working from an older printing of the first edition, which is even more out of date. You can install matplotlib in one line now: `python -m pip install --user matplotlib`. I highly recommend you pick up a copy of the second edition if you can, because the projects have had significant updates since your copy was produced.

Comment: I just ordered the 2nd edition. I put the line of code (python -m pip install --user matplotlib) in my Windows PowerShell, and it definitely downloaded the matplotlib, but I am still unfortunately unable to use it. The library is evidently stored in c:\users\bryan\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.3.4).  When I try to import matlplotlib, either with a Python program using Notepad++ (which I successfully used throughout the first 228 pages of your book) or with PowerShell, I get an error message. Pls help

Comment: >>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first .whl file is if you have 32 bit python, and the second .whl file is if you have  64 bit python.

You can check if you have 32 or 64 bit python with the below code:

```
import struct
print("You have", struct.calcsize("P") * 8, "bit Python. ")
```

Instead of downloading the .whl file, you can just use pip. You can install matplotlib with pip using this command: `python -m pip install matplotlib`. Replace python with python3 if python points to python2.

Comment: if my answer answered you question, please click on the checkmark, thanks!